# Trouble extracting/printing XML/XBRL values

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

I am trying to web scrape the SEC website for specific tags. The code that I have uses both XML and XBRL. I am not sure whether I should be using XML or XBRL to extract values from these tags that are located on the SEC. With this issue, I am printing a blank list with my code. Basically I wish to extract specific tags and I do not know whether to use XML or XBRL, and how to the print these tags with their values into a list.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
import requests

symbol = 'AAPL'
url = "https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=" + symbol + "&type=&dateb=&owner=exclude&start=0&count=100&output=atom"
uClient = uReq(url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
html = soup(page_html, 'html.parser')
entries = html.findAll("entry")


shouldContinue = True
link = ""
for entry in entries:

    if shouldContinue and (
            entry.find("category")["term"].lower() == "10-k" or entry.find("category")["term"].lower() == "10-q" or
            entry.find("category")["term"].lower() == "20-f"):


        firstUrl = entry.find("link")["href"]

        uClientFirstUrl = uReq(firstUrl)
        page_html_firstUrl = uClientFirstUrl.read()
        uClientFirstUrl.close()
        htmlFirstUrl = soup(page_html_firstUrl, 'html.parser')

        tds = htmlFirstUrl.findAll("table")[1].findAll("td")
        foundtd = False
        for td in tds:
            if foundtd == True:
                link = "https://www.sec.gov" + td.find("a")["href"]
                foundtd = False
            if "xbrl instance" in td.text.lower():
                foundtd = True

            shouldContinue = False


def getCash(url, symbol):
    uClient = uReq(url)
    page_html = uClient.read()
    uClient.close()
    xml = soup(page_html, 'xml')


    cash = xml.findAll("us-gaap:CashAndCashEquivalentsAtCarryingValue")
    if len(cash) == 0:
        cash = xml.findAll("ifrs-full:Cash")
        if len(cash) == 0:
            cash = xml.findAll("us-gaap:CashCashEquivalentsRestrictedCashAndRestrictedCashEquivalents")
            if len(cash) == 0:
                cash = xml.findAll("us-gaap:Cash")

    if not cash:
        print('No entries found.')

    return cash

print(getCash(url, symbol))
```

Comment: I don't see us-gaap:CashAndCashEquivalentsAtCarryingValue in the content of the url you supplied. I don't see cash tags either.

Comment: I believe that is what ```firstUrl``` brings you to; https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019320000010/0000320193-20-000010-index.htm. Then, ```uClientFirstUrl = uReq(firstUrl)``` to ```shouldContinue = False``` locates the XBRL file, in this case https://www.sec.gov/ix?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019320000010/a10-qq1202012282019.htm

Then in that link the cash tags can be found.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you want. Let's give you an example first. If there is a problem, let's continue to communicate.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,req,utils

# First page
symbol = 'AAPL'
url = "https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=" + symbol + "&type=&dateb=&owner=exclude&start=0&count=100&output=atom"
html = req.get(url)
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
links = doc.entrys.containsOr(['term="10-K"','term="10-Q"','term="20-F"']).link.href
# print (links)

# Second page
for link in links:
  html = req.get(link)
  doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
  # lstA = doc.select('table@summary=Data Files').selects('a') # Get all links in the table
  a = doc.select('table@summary=Data Files').getElementByText('XBRL INSTANCE',tag='td').getNext('a') # Use text to locate the link
  # print (utils.absoluteUrl(link,a.href),a.text)
  u = utils.absoluteUrl(link,a.href) # Third page
  html = req.get(u)
  doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
  cash = doc.selects('us-gaap:CashAndCashEquivalentsAtCarryingValue')
  if not cash:
    cash = doc.selects('ifrs-full:Cash')
  if not cash:
    cash = doc.selects('us-gaap:CashCashEquivalentsRestrictedCashAndRestrictedCashEquivalents')
  if not cash:
    cash = doc.selects('us-gaap:Cash')
  print (cash)
```

Result:

```
[{'tag': 'us-gaap:CashAndCashEquivalentsAtCarryingValue', 'contextRef': 'FI2020Q1', 'decimals': '-6', 'id': 'd57642648e573-wk-Fact-B1DF26F97E6F5D2D9418D8B9DDC1DB79', 'unitRef': 'usd', 'html': '39771000000'}, 
...
```

Comment: I am trying to print the one of the cash tags in this example, such as ```us-gaap:CashAndCashEquivalentsAtCarryingValue```

Comment: @dinosaurslayer I changed the answer.

Comment: I previously did not have simplified_scrapy installed on my PC. I just installed it via pip. I run the code and I get an error on line 1 stating that there is no module named 'simplified_scrapy'. Do I have to restart my PC after I install a module for it to work?

Comment: @dinosaurslayer No need to restart your PC. Maybe you installed it in a different Python version, try this. pip3 install simplified_scrapy

Comment: Hmm, both pip and pip3 don't seem to work. This is the error that I get ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/***/PycharmProjects/SECscrape/venv/cash1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,req,utils
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'simplified_scrapy'```

Comment: Ok I added the interpreter through my PyCharm settings. I'll get back in a bit.

Comment: @dinosaurslayer pycharm->File->Settings->Project Interpreter->your python path

Comment: @ dabingsou - I did just that and I get a few lines of errors now

Comment: @dinosaurslayer What kind of errors is this? Post it and let's have a look.

Comment: Okay, the error that I am getting is 
```
/Users/***/.conda/envs/webscrape1/bin/python /Users/***/PycharmProjects/webscrape1/webscrape1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/***/PycharmProjects/webscrape1/webscrape1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,req,utils
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'simplified_scrapy'

Process finished with exit code 1
```
I am not too sure how to fix this problem. I have tried to to import simplified scrapy module on my MacBook Air but I cannot find it. I also tried running Anaconda 3 interpreter

Comment: @dinosaurslayer There should be no such library in your Python path. Open your Python path and have a look. You can also copy the source code of simplified_scrapy library directly to the root directory of your project.

Comment: Okay I was able to locate simplified-scrapy and Scrapy module through the python interpreter by searching for the names in the search bar. However, by running the code I get 12 lines of really long code rather than one line of simplified code as shown in your result. Narrowing this down to retrieve the specific tag (in this case cash) would be really helpful.

Comment: @dinosaurslayer Yes, I added an ellipsis :)

Comment: From what I am understanding, it's printing multiple quarters arranged in a certain format. Narrowing it down to the most recent quarter would be ideal, as well as perhaps using the original modules. This will take some time to arrange I am presuming.